# How to extract years from a string in each row and generate new rows with those years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'business_id':["a","b","c"], 
                   'time':['2016-04-26 19:49:16, 2016-08-30 18:36:57, 2016-11-18 01:54:50, 2017-04-20 18:39:06', 
                           '2017-03-12 17:47:20, 2018-09-10 16:40:17',
                           '2014-02-28 12:11:16, 2019-05-30 18:36:57, 2019-07-20 04:54:28'] })
```

Here is the input generated from the above code.

```
business_id                                       time
      a            '2016-04-26 19:49:16, 2016-08-30 18:36:57, 2016-11-18 01:54:50, 2017-04-20 18:39:06'
      b                        '2017-03-12 17:47:20, 2018-09-10 16:40:17'
      c            '2014-02-28 12:11:16, 2019-05-30 18:36:57, 2019-07-20 04:54:28'
```

Below is the output I'd like to generate.

```
business_id                year
    a                      2016 
    a                      2016
    a                      2016
    a                      2017
    b                      2017
    b                      2018
    c                      2014
    c                      2019
    c                      2019
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the year and ID:

```
df[['business_id']].merge(df['time'].str
                        .extractall('(?P<year>\d{4})-')
                        .reset_index(1,drop=True),
                      left_index=True,
                      right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  business_id  year
0           a  2016
0           a  2016
0           a  2016
0           a  2017
1           b  2017
1           b  2018
2           c  2014
2           c  2019
2           c  2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with `explode` and then merge on the indexes.

```
(pd.merge(df['business_id'], 
           pd.to_datetime(df.time.str.split(',').explode()).dt.year, 
           left_index=True, 
           right_index=True))
```

---

```
  business_id  time
0           a  2016
0           a  2016
0           a  2016
0           a  2017
1           b  2017
1           b  2018
2           c  2014
2           c  2019
2           c  2019
```

Comment: Nice one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Made step by step, first start by formatting your dataframe correctly with `str.split(',')` and `explode()`. Then make sure the data is read as a datetime object with `pd.to_datetime`, finally `.dt.year` to get the year corresponding to the date:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  
df = pd.DataFrame({'business_id':["a","b","c"], 
                   'time':['2016-04-26 19:49:16, 2016-08-30 18:36:57, 2016-11-18 01:54:50, 2017-04-20 18:39:06', 
                           '2017-03-12 17:47:20, 2018-09-10 16:40:17',
                           '2014-02-28 12:11:16, 2019-05-30 18:36:57, 2019-07-20 04:54:28']})
df['aux'] = df['time'].str.split(',')
df = df.drop('time',axis=1)
df = df.explode('aux')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['aux'])
df = df.drop('aux',axis=1)
df['year'] = df['time'].dt.year
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
  business_id                time  year
0           a 2016-04-26 19:49:16  2016
0           a 2016-08-30 18:36:57  2016
0           a 2016-11-18 01:54:50  2016
0           a 2017-04-20 18:39:06  2017
1           b 2017-03-12 17:47:20  2017
```